# numer specific items in ng-repeat (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Assume the following object

```
var items [
    { type: 'big', .... },
    { type: 'small', .... },
    { type: 'big', .... },
    { type: 'small', .... },
    { type: 'big', .... },
];
```

Which I use inside a `ng-repeat` as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <span ng-if="item.type === 'big'>{{$index}}</div>
   <p> ..... </p>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is that I only want to number the items with `type === 'big'` and I don't wan't gapes in the numbering. The output now is:

```
<div>
   <span>0</div>
   <p>......</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>......</p>
</div>
<div>
   <span>2</div> // I want a 1 here
   <p>......</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>......</p>
</div>
<div>
   <span>4</div> // and a 2 here!
   <p>......</p>
</div>
```

What would be the angular way to perform this kind of numbering ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I am proposing isn't an Angular solution at all. But instead I am going to use CSS to solve your solely displaying issue:

CSS counters are implemented in all major browsers and therefore a usable possibility ([canIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters))

You reset an css counter for the sorrounding element and increment it for every shown element:

```
<div class="list">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
       <p ng-class="item.type"> ..... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and trhe corresponding CSS:

```
.list{
    counter-reset: big-counter;
}

.list .big:before {
    content: counter(big-counter);
    counter-increment: big-counter;
}
```

I made **[this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H1DQUjQgZYKhoy0Rv7c1?p=preview)** to show the result.

---

### Update

To use characters instead of numbers you change the css counter line to the following:

```
content: counter(big-counter,lower-latin);
```

or

```
content: counter(big-counter, upper-latin);
```

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/M6TjgCpM1bXIP8NTvJ3I?p=preview) (by Jeanluca Scaljeri)

Comment: This is actually a very nice one, however, in my application I need eventually  characters instead of numbers :( Thnx!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri How should your output look like if you do have characters in it, can you show us an example? Maybe we can tweak the CSS solution somehow...

Comment: Well, instead of numbering I place `a`, `b`, `c`, etc in front of it. The answer given by @ustinpinili works fine, because I just add 96  and use `fromCharCode`

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri This is till possible with CSS counters, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: awesome, thats exactly what I need! (I've updated your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M6TjgCpM1bXIP8NTvJ3I?p=preview))

Answer (score 3):

You could call a scoped function in your `ng-if` statement that will check if the `item.type === "big"` and also keeps track of the number of times `item.type !== "big"` and subtract that number from the index of the repeated element.

Inside your Angular controller:

```
$scope.skipped = 0;
$scope.isBig = function(type) {
  if (type === "big") {
    return true;
  else {
    $scope.skipped++;
    return false;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <span ng-if="isBig(item.type)">{{$index - skipped}}</div>
   <p> ..... </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't angular, it's math

```
<span ng-if="item.type === 'big'>{{$index/2}}</div>
```

Just divide the index by 2!

Sure, you could do some funny stuff in the controller, but this is probably the fastest and easiest.

Comment: If the answer works, don't downvote it unless you comment on it to explain your issue. They call that "basic civility".

Comment: you'r right about the answer producing the correct output, but if the data changes it won't work anymore.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri yes, you are right, but any change would affect underlying logic too. Ah well, whatever.